# changing date/time variable to time that starts at 00:00:00 in r

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time

I'm looking for a simple and correct way to change the date/time (POSIXct) format into a time that starts at 00:00:00.

I couldn't find an answer to this in R language, but if I overlooked one, please tell me :)

So I have this :

| date/time | v1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-16 15:07:15 | 38937 |
| 2022-02-16 15:07:17 | 39350 |

And I would like this :

| time | v1 |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:00 | 38937 |
| 00:00:02 | 39350 |

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks :)

Comment: what should `time` look like on `date/time` different dates?

Answer (score 0):

You can deduct all `date/time` with the first record of `date/time`, and change the result to type of `time` by the `hms()` function in the `hms` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(hms)

df %>% 
  mutate(`date/time` = hms::hms(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(`date/time`) - as.POSIXct(first(`date/time`)))))

 date/time    v1
1  00:00:00 38937
2  00:00:02 39350
```

Note that in this method, even if the time difference is greater than 1 day, it'll be reflected in the result, for example:

```
df <- read.table(header = T, check.names = F, sep = "\t", text = "
date/time   v1
2022-02-16 15:07:15 38937
2022-02-18 15:07:17 39350")

df %>% 
  mutate(`date/time` = hms::hms(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(`date/time`) - as.POSIXct(first(`date/time`)))))

  date/time    v1
1  00:00:00 38937
2  48:00:02 39350
```

Comment: Note that if the result is a tibble, then the times will be formatted as `00'02"`.

Comment: @jpiversen That's how tibble displays "time" if it's less than 1 hour

Comment: True. It was just a note, since I interpreted OPs question as "how to get difftimes formatted as `00:00:02`", and if formatting is important one should probably use strings. `time` values are better for further analysis though, so it's just a matter of interpretation of OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference between the two datetimes in seconds, and add i to a random date starting at "00:00:00", before formatting it to only including the time. See the `time` column in the reprex underneath:

```r
library(dplyr)
ibrary(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    date = lubridate::ymd_hms(date),
    seconds = as.numeric(date - first(date)),
    time = format(
      lubridate::ymd_hms("2022-01-01 00:00:00") + seconds, 
      format = "%H:%M:%S"
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   date                   v1 seconds time    
#>   <dttm>              <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 2022-02-16 15:07:15 38937       0 00:00:00
#> 2 2022-02-16 15:07:17 39350       2 00:00:02
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

> Note that this will be misleading if you ever have over 24 hours between two datetimes. In these cases you should probably include the date.

#### Data

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~date,    ~v1,
  "2022-02-16 15:07:15",    38937,
  "2022-02-16 15:07:17",    39350
)
```